# Adding custom datatype in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, organization

I'm using the scaffolded yesod template and want to add a new type for monetary values. Ideally this should be done in one file called Money.hs for example. But this will form cyclic imports:

- Foundation imports Model.
- The new Money type will be used in the model to store monetary
  values. Therefore Model will have to import Money
- Money will have to import foundation for a `moneyField :: Field
  Handler Money` function

TL DR: Is there a "correct" way to add new types to a scaffolded yesod application including sql db type, shakespeare field widget and `ToHtml` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your third bullet: why do you need to reference `Handler`? You can structure your field code the same way as the built in fields in [Yesod.Form.Fields](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-11-02/yesod-form-1.4.5/Yesod-Form-Fields.html), e.g.:

```
textField :: Monad m => RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage => Field m Text
```

With that: I'd say that a `Money.hs` (or even `Data/Money.hs`) makes the most sense.

Comment: That works, thanks. Another quick question, how can I marshal my type to a database value? I have a `PersistField` instance but `PersistFieldSql` seems to be hidden and I need both(I think).

Comment: That class is exposed from Database.Persist.Sql. See: http://www.stackage.org/lts-3.12/hoogle?q=PersistFieldSql&exact=on